# Swapping columns - first-child last-child - Bootstrap

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

Im trying to alternate the layout of some rows I have. They should look like this:

[image]

It's in bootstrap and there is a loop outputting each row. The output looks like this:

```
<div class="container benefit-container">
    <div class="row benefit-row">

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-text">
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#">...</a>          
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-image">
            <img src="#" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row benefit-row">

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-text">
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#">...</a>          
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-image">
            <img src="#" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row benefit-row">

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-text">
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#">...</a>          
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 benefit-image">
            <img src="#" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

So for each .benefit-row I'm trying to swap around the .benefit-text and benefit-image.

I can manage to swap them around using this:

```
.benefit-row div:first-child {
  left: 50%;
}
.benefit-row div:last-child {
  right: 50%;
}
```

But to alternate the rows, I think I need to utilise the nth-child odd and even CSS.

But I'm not sure how to implement it. It almost needs to be an if statement such as, if row is odd then first child 50% and last child 50%...

Can this even be done with CSS alone? Perhaps I need to write my css inline and use php somehow?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks for looking!

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: Because I mentioned it might be something I need to put inline and use php - I thought to  add some sort off statement for odd and even...

Comment: you don't need PHP for that, css has already a pseudo for that `:nth-child(odd)`

Comment: I know that - but I wanted to combine that with the first and last child and THAT is why I mentioned php because I’m not sure I can combine both bits of css, so I thought there might be another solution...

Comment: you could make it more complicated and add an ternary in looping the rows `<?php echo ($k & 1) ? 'alternate-class: ''; ?>`

Comment: If that’s more complicated, I’m assuming you know if an easier way, so... you know... you could actually also try to offer some help... or not.

Comment: @ShaunTaylor like I said, i'd prefer to use [css](https://www.tehplayground.com/RJbf9NMQHWHt0u4r) for that. instead of having [class toggle](https://www.tehplayground.com/R0jNyUClBfxAhzui) with ternary inside the loop and whatnot

Comment: you can use the bitwise version `($k & 1)` or the modulo version `($k % 2 === 0)`, it'll yield the same effect

Comment: Well, thanks for your help Kevin. Any chance you could help me out if I removed the php tag? Is that the thing that’s stopping you? Or don’t you know what the answer might be?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t really know how I would apply that - I don’t know what bitwise or modulo is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217852/discussion-between-kevin-and-shaun-taylor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments above it's preferable to just use CSS for this task alone using `odd` css pseudo selectors:

```
.benefit-row:nth-child(odd) div:first-child {
    left: 50%;
}
.benefit-row:nth-child(odd) div:last-child {
    right: 50%;
}
```

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4a6yb7L/)

This yields something like this:

[image]

Rather than using PHP and adding some odd and even with ternary

```
<style type="text/css">
.benefit-row.alt div:first-child {
  left: 50%;
}
.benefit-row.alt div:last-child {
  right: 50%;
}
</style>
<?php $k = 1; ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row benefit-row <?php echo ($k++ & 1) ? 'alt' : '' ?>">
        <div class="col-6 bg-primary">1</div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-secondary">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row benefit-row <?php echo ($k++ & 1) ? 'alt' : '' ?>">
        <div class="col-6 bg-primary">1</div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-secondary">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row benefit-row <?php echo ($k++ & 1) ? 'alt' : '' ?>">
        <div class="col-6 bg-primary">1</div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-secondary">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically yields the [same result](https://www.tehplayground.com/I7huQT22wupXjXrO):

[image]

But with uglier code. So use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: That's awesome, Kevin, thanks so much for writing that out! :) I'll use the CSS - I was just having trouble working out how to combine the two selectors and wondered if I needed to use PHP or even jQuery - but it seems I can just use CSS :) Thanks again!